# Call a protected API on Azure Functions from Blazor WebAssembly

Tags: c#, azure, authentication, blazor, authorization

I have two C# projects.

The first project is a C# .NET 7 out-of-process Azure Functions used as backend API.
The endpoints are protected using *Azure App Service Authentication* with Azure Active Directory B2B.
These are the Authentication and the app registration settings:
[image]
[image][image]
[image]
Others relevant informations about the registration app are:

- The app have a custom application ID URI and an exposed API 'user_impersonation' (`api://NAME/user_impersonation`)
- The allowed token audiences is set to the application ID URI (`api://NAME`)
- The app have both the Blazor frontend callback endpoint (set as SPA) and the Azure Functions self-exposed authorization endpoints (set as Web) set as redirect URI

---

The second project is a frontend written in Blazor WASM .NET 7 that should be published on an Azure Static Website.
The Blazor frontend needs to call the protected endpoint on the Azure Functions.
The Authentication is done using the MSAL Authentication library:

```
builder.Services.AddMsalAuthentication(options => {
    builder.Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options.ProviderOptions.Authentication);
    options.ProviderOptions.DefaultAccessTokenScopes.Add(builder.Configuration["AzureAd:Scopes"]!);
})
```

`AzureAd:Scopes` is the previous 'user_impersionation' (`api://NAME/user_impersonation`) and the app is the same.

If I try to login via Blazor everything works correctly, but when I try to make an API call Azure always returns 401 Unauthorized.

Ultimately I was not able to find a good solution to incorporate Azure Functions Authentication with Blazor's builtin Authentication system.
I've tried to:

- Attaching the access token to both `Authorization` and `X-ZUMO-AUTH` headers.
- Use different apps for client and API (by creating another app and adding the exposed API as a scope).
- Using the [Authentication Flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-authentication-authorization) with provider SDK by extending the `AccountClaimsPrincipalFactory`, requesting the authentication code from `/.auth/login/aad` by passing the access token got from `IAccessTokenProvider`. But I always receive 401 Unauthorized.
- Trying to use the [Authentication Flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-authentication-authorization) without provider SDK, but I didn't find any solution to implement that in Blazor without implementing a custom Authorization provider.

I don't think I'm trying to make some strange edge-case implementation, but I was not able to find anything working for me.
I just need to call an API hosted in Azure Functions and protected, in some way, by requiring an authenticated AAD user, from a client Blazor hosted on Azure Static Website (on different domains).

So either, I'm using the wrong Authentication system, or there is something that I'm missing.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to set the CORS settings on the Azure Function. I had a similar issue on a small Blazor WASM app running locally attempting to get data from an Azure Function running in Azure. The call to Http.GetFromJsonAsync would hit an exception until I set CORS up properly for the Azure Function on the Azure Portal. Just a thought...

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).